# Python: parsing ESMA (european financial authority) XML files

Tags: python, xml

I tried to parse the XML files found here:

https://registers.esma.europa.eu/publication/searchRegister?core=esma_registers_fitrs_files

using `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse()`

These files contain security ISINs and trade volume data enforced by MiFIR reporting regulations.

I couldn't locate anything with findall() or find(). Looping over childs and grandchilds seems to work, but the depth of the tree is crazy.

I want to extract ISINs and data per 'NonEqtyTrnsprncyData' Node. I tried

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
tree = parse("FULNCR_20191005_D_1of10.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
elems = root.findall('NonEqtyTrnsprncyData')
```

only gives me [] in elems.

Using the same logic for a sample database `mondial-3.0.xml` worked flawlessly at my first effort.

Does anybody here has successfully parsed ESMA xml files and can boost my learning curve?

A short version of the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BizData
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01 head.003.001.01.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.003.001.01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Hdr>
        <AppHdr
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01 head.001.001.01_ESMAUG_1.0.0.xsd"
            xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Fr>
                <OrgId>
                    <Id>
                        <OrgId>
                            <Othr>
                                <Id>EU</Id>
                            </Othr>
                        </OrgId>
                    </Id>
                </OrgId>
            </Fr>
            <To>
                <OrgId>
                    <Id>
                        <OrgId>
                            <Othr>
                                <Id>Public</Id>
                            </Othr>
                        </OrgId>
                    </Id>
                </OrgId>
            </To>
            <BizMsgIdr>FULNCR_20191005_D_3of10</BizMsgIdr>
            <MsgDefIdr>auth.045.001.02</MsgDefIdr>
            <CreDt>2019-10-05T13:00:01Z</CreDt>
        </AppHdr>
    </Hdr>
    <Pyld>
        <Document
            xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02 auth.045.001.02_ESMAUG_DATNCR_1.1.0.xsd"
            xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <FinInstrmRptgNonEqtyTradgActvtyRslt>
                <RptHdr>
                    <RptgNtty>
                        <NtlCmptntAuthrty>EU</NtlCmptntAuthrty>
                    </RptgNtty>
                    <RptgPrd>
                        <FrDtToDt>
                            <FrDt>2019-10-05</FrDt>
                            <ToDt>2019-10-11</ToDt>
                        </FrDtToDt>
                    </RptgPrd>
                </RptHdr>
                <NonEqtyTrnsprncyData>
                    <TechRcrdId>1</TechRcrdId>
                    <Id>CH0110680714</Id>
                    <FinInstrmClssfctn>BOND</FinInstrmClssfctn>
                    <RptgPrd>
                        <FrDtToDt>
                            <FrDt>2018-01-01</FrDt>
                            <ToDt>2018-03-31</ToDt>
                        </FrDtToDt>
                    </RptgPrd>
                    <Lqdty>false</Lqdty>
                </NonEqtyTrnsprncyData>
            </FinInstrmRptgNonEqtyTradgActvtyRslt>
        </Document>
    </Pyld>
</BizData>
```

where I delete all the NonEqtyTrnsprncyData elements but one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- `Element.findall()` with just a tagname can only ever find *direct children*; from the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements):

  > `Element.findall()` finds only elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element.

  You want to use an [XPath expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) instead here; prefixing a tag name with `.//` tells the API to search for subelements *on all levels beneath the current element*.
- The XML document uses [XML namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace); the element you are looking for is part of the `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02` namespace; this was set on the `Document` parent element with the `xmlns="..."` attribute, which looks like this (ignoring other attributes):

  ```xml
  <Document
      xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02"
      >
  ```

  `xmlns` attributes, with or without a prefix (e.g. `xmlns:prefix`) apply to the element they are defined on and the whole subtree until another such attribute overrides the setting.

  Note that prefixes such as `xsi` are usually document local, so it doesn't really matter what the prefix is; it's the URI that names the namespace.

So you want to use a namespace, and you want to use an XPath expression. It's easiest to use (your own) prefix to make writing XPath expressions easier. This will find your elements:

```
namespace = 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02'
elems = tree.findall('.//ns:NonEqtyTrnsprncyData', {'ns': namespace})
```

You can also use `.//{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02}NonEqtyTrnsprncyData` as the expression, and not use a namespace prefix and map, but that just becomes very verbose when used more than once.

You also don't need to call `tree.getroot()`; you can use `tree.findall()` directly because we are using an XPath expression that is designed to search the whole tree here anyway.

Demo:

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
>>> tree = parse("FULNCR_20191005_D_1of10.xml")
>>> namespace = 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02'
>>> elems = tree.findall('.//ns:NonEqtyTrnsprncyData', {'ns': namespace})
>>> len(elems)
1
>>> elems[0]
<Element '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02}NonEqtyTrnsprncyData' at 0x109a84400>
>>> list(elems[0])
[<Element '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02}TechRcrdId' at 0x109a844a0>, <Element '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02}Id' at 0x109a84540>, <Element '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02}FinInstrmClssfctn' at 0x109a845e0>, <Element '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02}RptgPrd' at 0x109a84680>, <Element '{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02}Lqdty' at 0x109a849a0>]
```

Note that all the elements returned by the API have *fully qualified names*; if you have a document with a variable set of namespaces you could parse the namespace out of the tagname:

```
>>> prefix, has_namespace, remainder = elems[0].tag.partition("}")
>>> if has_namespace:
...     namespace, tag = prefix[1:], remainder
... else:
...     namespace, tag = None, prefix
...
>>> namespace, tag
('urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:auth.045.001.02', 'NonEqtyTrnsprncyData')
```

You may also want to look at the [`lxml` project](https://lxml.de/index.html), which builds out on the same ElementTree API but is faster and provides more features, such as much better namespace handling and complete XPath 1.0 support (the Python standard library ElementTree implementation is much more limited).